# understanding example of a family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This example is from the Wikipedia page on "family of sets":

[image]

I don't understand what elements of $S$ have to do with $A_1,A_2,...$etc, and how are they matched? $S$ has five elements yet $F$ has four. Why is $A_2$ the same as $A_3$?
I don't understand this example of a family of sets. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: The amin point is $A_k\subseteq S$. And that $A_2=A_3$ is allowed in the sense of multisets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A family of sets over $S$ can also be defined as a function having some indexset $I$ as domain and the powerset $\wp\left(S\right)$ as codomain. Here $I=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $i\mapsto A_i$ as prescription of the function. The function is not demanded to be injective so $A_2=A_3$ is possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the same article on Wikipedia:

> A collection F of subsets of a given set S is called a family of
>   subsets of S

Here, $A_1, A_2, ..., A_4$ are each an arbitrary subset of S. F is a collection of subsets of S. This does not mean F should have the same number of members.

> The term "collection" is used here because, in some contexts, a family
>   of sets may be allowed to contain repeated copies of any given member.

This answers the question of why $A_2$ and $A_3$ can be the same: members of multisets (aka collections) can be repeated.